Spring Boot RabbitMQ configured concurrency not working
I am trying to make consuming messages from a RabbitMQ Queue more efficient.
I am unable to get my Spring configuration to work with RabbitMQ SimpleMessageListenerContainer where I have configured concurrency and prefetch count.
Spring Boot 3.2.5
Spring Cloud 2023.0.1
spring-cloud-stream
spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit
Java 21
RabbitMQ Server running version 3.6.12
spring:
  application:
    name: app-third
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${RABBITMQ_URL:localhost}
    port: ${RABBITMQ_PORT:5672}
    virtual-host: ${RABBITMQ_VIRTUALHOST:}
    username: ${RABBITMQ_USER:guest}
    password: ${RABBITMQ_PASS:guest}
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          max-attempts: 3
        concurrency: 5
        max-concurrency: 25
        prefetch: 10
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: process
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: app.third-request
          group: app-third
        process-out-0:
          destination: app.third-response
          group: app-third
  threads:
    virtual:
      enabled: true

My Custom TaskExecutor Bean
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(400);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}

I am able to get this to work only if I create a Custom Bean of SimpleMessageListenerContainer.
The RabbitMQ server now gets 6 consumers (should be 5).
Five of the consumers have prefetch count 10, while One has prefetch count 1.
I suspect the SimpleMessageListenerContainer it is the one from the Spring configuration, in addition to the one I created with the custom Bean.
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    @Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter
) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("app.third-request.app-third");
    container.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(50);
    container.setPrefetchCount(10);
    return container;
}

However this will not work with my Function<Request, Response> for the Message Queue. I would need to create a MessageListenerAdapter to read the messages.
Log Output:
[           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Changing consumers from 1 to 1
[           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : No global properties bean
[           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Starting Rabbit listener container.
[    app-third-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@13ddaffb: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[    app-third-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Started on queue 'app.third-request.app-third' with tag amq.ctag-zP9jnSC-NwTYivlWOLf2kw: 
  Consumer@13ddaffb: tags=[[]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance,1), 
  conn: Proxy@51172948 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@fe13916 [delegate=amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance, localPort=55370], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

[           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Starting Rabbit listener container.
[ taskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@1ee22768: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[ taskExecutor-5] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@38a52072: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[ taskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@746f8520: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[ taskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@6108fd23: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[ taskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@3d3a28b5: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[ taskExecutor-5] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance,3)
[ taskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance,4)
[ taskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance,2)
[ taskExecutor-4] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance,6)
[ taskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance,5)
[ taskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Started on queue 'app.third-request.app-third' with tag amq.ctag-HrAsdYteFh7S8s2KPZsrDg: 
    Consumer@1ee22768: tags=[[]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance,2), 
    conn: Proxy@51172948 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@fe13916 [delegate=amqp://rabbitmq-instance@10.244.52.31:5672/rabbitmq-instance, localPort=55370], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
4 More Started on queue

How can I get the SimpleMessageListenerContainer from my Spring Configuration to work as configured with concurrency and prefetch count?
It does not seem like Spring and/or RabbitMQ is using my listener configuration.
I have created a sample application that demonstrates this problem.
https://github.com/DJViking/spring-boot-rabbitmq-demo
Running this Spring Boot example will fire up a RabbitMQ instance and configure a queue similar to my application.

After digging in the Spring source code I found out that this listener properties are only used for SimpleMessageListenerContainer constructed by use of @RabbitListener annotated methods. Not sure if how or if possible to get this working with cloud function definitions.

It seems like when using Spring Cloud Stream Functional programming model, the concurrency configuration must be in spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings, and not the spring.rabbitmq.listener.

When using Spring Cloud Stream with Functional programming model then I had to use spring.cloud.stream.binders configuration properties, and not spring.rabbitmq.listener properties
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: processPayment
    stream:
      bindings:
        processPayment-in-0:
          destination: demo.payment-request
          group: demo-payment
        processPayment-out-0:
          destination: demo.payment-response
          group: demo-payment
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          processPayment-in-0:
            consumer:
              prefetch: 10
              single-active-consumer: false
              max-concurrency: 25
              container-type: simple


Although there is one think I could not find solutuion for.
How to start a minimum number of consumers like the spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency.
